# Android app not receiving FCM push messages

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to send push messages from Firebase to my Android application:

Both of the `MyFirebaseInstanceIDService` and `MyFirebaseMessagingService` class are inside the service package of my main package. Below is my folder structure

[image]

So in my AndroidManifest they are represented as

```
<service
    android:name=".services.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<service
    android:name=".services.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

MyFirebaseInstanceIDService class:

```
public class MyFirebaseInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

    private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseInstanceIDService.class.getSimpleName();
    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        Log.d(TAG, "-------- refreshedToken: " + refreshedToken);
        

        //TODO: send the token to the node server to store it in mysql


    }
}
```

MyFirebaseMessagingService class:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    private static final String TAG = MyFirebaseMessagingService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());

        if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
        }

        if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "280887");
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("FCM Notification");
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

    }
}
```

The issue is when I run my app I do not get the registration token. All the examples I have seen online or youtube, they have all their files under single package. But in my case I got sub-packages for each type of file. Is this is issue?

Also, in MyFirebaseInstanceIDService when I store the token in shared preference and retrieve it in HomeActivity the token is null.

***************** EDIT*****************

My Logcat gives `Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used` message. It is not showing any tags V, I, D non of them

Comment: did you add you project in firbase  and download google.json ?

Comment: Yes, that is also done.

Comment: you got the token only first time when app install on your phone. try to uninstall the app and again install

Comment: Welcome to the club !!! There are series of issues reported to Firebase, but they don't seem to even acknowledge. There are various permutations, for most of the time, Firebase messaging does not work on emulator, and it does not work when an app is reinstalled by debugger, it works first time. Look for log that will say something like Firebase initialization failed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your project in Firebase and then download a file named "google.json" and insert it inside your project. otherwise the authentication will fail and you won't receive any token.
Also you won't receive any new token until it changes.
on the other hand, Google usually doesn't send pushes immediately specially on Debug mode.

Comment: I forgot to mention it in the question but I have done those steps

Comment: My Logcat gives Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used message. It is not showing any tags V, I, D non of them. So I think even if the token is sent, I cannot view it

Comment: Ok, just in case of debugging, save your token inside a SharedPreferences and check its value every time your app is created. Do you send the token anywhere?

Comment: Well I am storing inside the shared preference but the Logcat is not printing it out. I am printing the token on the SplashActivity but it gives - Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used

Comment: Does your debug package name differs with the release one? Cause the package names must be exactly the same with your google.json file.

Comment: The package name I have given in firebase is: com.dev.gideon where in my project the firebase classes are located in com.dev.gideon.services, the activity is in com.dev.gideon.activity -- see the project structure image i have uploaded

Comment: ok finally got the reg token when I did FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()

Comment: @codeinprogress well perfect! about your previous comment, the package name may have some extensions base on your buildTypes inside the Gradle file, this is why I asked about that.

Answer (score 0):

### Send Registration To Server

Make sure you have added your project to **Firebase** and downloaded the correct ***google-services.json*** file and placed it in the **Apps** folder

*Use the code similar to the one below and Register the token to the Server*

```
package com.dev.gideon.services;


import [LOCATION-TO-YOUR-SHAREDPREF].SharedPref;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

public class FcmInstanceIDService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {


    private SharedPref sharedPref;

    @Override
    public void onTokenRefresh() {
        sharedPref = new SharedPref(this);
        String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
        sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
    }

    private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
        sharedPref.setFcmRegId(token);
        sharedPref.setOpenAppCounter(SharedPref.MAX_OPEN_COUNTER);
    }
}
```

Try if it Helps!!!

Comment: Storing inside the shared preference but Logcat wont print it. I get: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
                                                    adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.dev.gideon
09-21 13:16:54.162 3848-3884/com.dev.gideon I/FA: Tag Manager is not found and thus will not be used